# Recaptcha Request is returning Null

Tags: php, json, curl, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement this Recaptcha request into my sign-up form, however it isn't working. The cURL/JSON request returns `null` when I successfully validate the Recaptcha on my website.

I tried using `var_dump` on the `"error-codes":` from the JSON request, and it only returns null; whereas in [this document](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) it shows that it is clearly meant to output two items in the JSON request.

Thanks in advance, I haven't done much work with JSON/cURL, so be easy on me.

Here's my code:

PHP

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        if(!empty($recaptcha)) {

            function getCurlData($url) {
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
                $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                return $curlData;
            }

            $google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
            $secret = 'You will never know >:D';
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $url = $google_url . "?secret=" . $secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha . "&remoteip=" . $ip;
            $res = getCurlData($url);
            $res = json_decode($res, true);

            // var_dumping returns null
            var_dump($res);

            //reCaptcha success check 
            if($res['success'] == true) {
                echo "Recaptcha was successfully validated";
            } else {
                echo "Recaptcha was not validated, please try again";
            }
        } else {
            echo "You didn't validate the Recaptcha";
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="home.php" method="post">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="I removed it for this post"></div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is my code running without problem:

**Client Side:**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PUBLIC_KEY"></div>
```

**Server Side:**

```
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $privatekey = "SECRET_KEY";
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => $privatekey,
        'response' => $captcha,
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );

    $curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

$jsonResponse = json_decode($response);

if ($jsonResponse->success === true) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    doSomeOtherThing();
}
```

Working [here](http://www.peluqueriapilarsilvan.com/contacto)! :)

Comment: 'success' MUST be in boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably with the SSL certificate.
You can put this line to let curl ignore it:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)
```

However, you can put this to test on your localhost but when uploading your website, it is better to have an SSL certificate and this line removed.

Comment: This is what worked for me, I'm testing in local and the SSL Verifypeer never works for me in that situation.

Comment: Happy to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Api says: METHOD: POST, you are sending "GET" request.
Check `CURLOPT_POST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option on http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

EDIT:
I just checked the API, it work with GET too. I don't see any error in your code. Could you temporary change your function to:

```
   function getCurlData($url) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
        $curlData = curl_exec($curl);

        if (!$curlData) {
            throw new \Exception('Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl));
        }
        curl_close($curl);


        return $curlData;
    }
```

Comment: Where does it say I'm using a GET request? And when can I implement 'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS', I'm not familiar with this so I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Default request is ``GET``, you don't specify request type => you are making GET request. Check **documentation** and **examples**, there at least 3 ways to specify the POST fields.

Comment: If you look at my code I have POST specified, I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your curl request should be POST. ``curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);``.And post options too ``curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, {{your post data here}});``

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know where to put that. Can you post an answer highlighting where you put it? :)

Comment: No, I won't :P
You should place the code above ``$curlData = curl_exec($curl);``. {{ your post data here}} should be the **secret** and the **response**, encoded for ``curl_setopt``, e.g. ``secret=xxxx&response=userResponse``. You don't have these params in your function. You need to change it and provide them as params, or extract them from url :)

Comment: I'm a noob at this, so sorry I'm still having a hard time implementing it. Can you please post an answer with all of this so I can see?

Comment: Does CURLOPT_URL mean its a get request? I'm having trouble, please help I need to finish this

Comment: Hey, I just tried it and I got this error:

'unable to get local issuer certificate'

Comment: please, I've been trying to fix this for ages

Comment: @mightyspaj3 Did you solve the problem? Because I'm in the same situation!