# google recaptcha response is null [PHP, localhost]

Tags: php, forms, validation, recaptcha

I need a little help for a problem with Google Recaptcha in a site I am developing in my pc (so localhost) before transferring to the open internet.

I signed up for Google Recaptcha and got a pair of keys. I created this form in a php page:

```
<div>
  <form action="" method="POST" name="formEmail">
    <section>
      <ul class="formMail" id="ulMsg">
        <li>
          <label for="msg">Messagge</label>
        </li><li>
          <textarea class="datoForm autoExpand" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Type Msg" rows='3' data-min-rows='3'></textarea>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <div class="formMail" id="captchaContainer">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[Public_Key]"></div>
    </div>
    <br/><input type="button" value="Invia" onclick="formSubmit();">                            
  </form>
</div>
```

Instead of a submit button I call a JS file to validate user input, if everything is fine I submit data to another php page which checks captcha too. Source of this php page is:

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){$captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];}
$secretKey = "[Private_Key]";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
```

Here is the problem: I don't get anything! I tried

```
var_dump($responseKeys);
```

but all I get is NULL. I do not get any other error, the captcha shows fine in the form and seems to work regularly. I am working in localhost, so my IP is 127.0.0.1, this should help but is useless. I do not have an "open" site to paste it and try, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem. It was a `<div>` tag causing the problem.

My form was within a main `<div>` used to format the general layout of the form. The `<form>` tag doesn't HAVE to be within the main `<div>` I was using for the form layout. I moved the `<form>` tag just before my form layout `<div>` tag and it started working perfectly.

The same can happen with `<table>` tags. You need to start the `<form>` tag before any tables used for formatting the form.

So your problem is the `<div>` just before the `<form>`:

`<div>
<form action="" method="POST" name="formEmail">`

Just reverse the 2 tags and it will work fine:

`<form action="" method="POST" name="formEmail">
<div>`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google recaptcha documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request):

> Method: POST

But you are sending a `GET` request on this line:

```
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
```

A solution has already been proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29827326/7094618).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. I found that code in many tutorials over the internet so I assumed it worked. Unfortunately, I tried the solution you suggested but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I had some stupid scenario.

In the rush, I put the client code for recaptcha **OUTSIDE** of the `<form>` element.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_code"></div>
```

So when the form was submitted, the `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` was returning null because there wasn't such element INSIDE The `<form>` tag.

The reason for my decision was that I had a submit button outside of my form because of design purposes. I used the property: `form="your_form_id"`:

```
<button id="btnSave" name="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="reviewForm">Submit</button>
```

So the **solution** was to just insert the g-recaptcha code **INSIDE** the `<form>` tag:

```
    <form> 
        ....... your form code here 
        
             <div class="text-center">
                 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le1cx4nAAAAAI7MJXRUAX0J1Vp5p9fj86wW08qz" style="    display: inline-block;">
            
                  </div>
             </div>

       <!-- RECAPTCHA BEFORE THE END OF THE FORM -->

       </form>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Inside HTML Tags :

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST">

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="PublicKey"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post comment">

</form>

</body>
```

Inside PHP Tags :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if( isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
        $secret = 'PrivateKey';
        $verifyResponse=file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        var_dump($responseData); //this line returns Null Value

        if($responseData->success) {
            // Logical Code
        }
        else {
            echo 'Robot verification failed, please try again.';
        } 
    }
}

?>
```